# Can I add a display name attribute on the fly if one isnt specified in MVC3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I was thinking it would be super cool if I could hook up something that would add a display name attribute on the fly to any model property that didnt already have one. The idea would be that if I have a property called FirstName I could just tiltlize it and make it "First Name"

MVC seems to have a provider model for everything.  Is there anything I could use to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.  You just need to create your own ModelMetaDataprovider and override the DisplayName.

Answer (score 3):

This is just the expanded version of Doug's answer

```
public class MyModelMetadataProvider : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
{
    public override ModelMetadata GetMetadataForProperty(Func<object> modelAccessor, Type containerType, string propertyName)
    {
        var result = base.GetMetadataForProperty(modelAccessor, containerType, propertyName);
        if (result.DisplayName.IsEmpty()) result.DisplayName = propertyName.InflectTo().Titleized;
        return result;
    }
}
```

and register it with mvc in the global asax like so:

```
ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new MyModelMetadataProvider();
```

Comment: Could you provide more details on that `.InflectTo()` extension method?

Answer (score -1):

You can Use [DisplayName] attribute to achieve the goal For property, if  You want to use for Model Basis, Then GoFor MOdelMetaDataProvider

[ModelMetaDataProvider MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelmetadataprovider.aspx)

[Sample Tutorial for ModelMetaDataProvider](http://weblogs.asp.net/seanmcalinden/archive/2010/06/11/custom-asp-net-mvc-2-modelmetadataprovider-for-using-custom-view-model-attributes.aspx)

[Another Sample For ModelMetaDataProvider](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Customizing-ASP-NET-MVC-2-Metadata-and-Validation.aspx)